# Python: retirar aspas duplas de uma lista

Tags: python-3.x

Senhores(as), preciso **retirar as aspas duplas de cada índice da lista** e, gostaria de **remover cada espaço em vazio**, assim como **retirar aquele '\n'** do final da lista.

```
lista = ['"11/07/2019"', '"00:58:40"', '"087974440345"', '""', '"Cancelamento automático"\n', '""\n']
```

Se eu usar:

```
print(''.join(lista).replace('"', "'"))
```

O resultado não será o desejado.
O resultado será (em duas linhas):

```
'11/07/2019''00:58:40''087974440345''''Cancelamento automático'
''
```

Preciso manter a estrutura de lista, com as vírgulas separando cada termo da lista, pois eu irei fazer outras tarefas com essa lista.

Podem ajudar-me? Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Não** precisa converter para string com `.join()` e usar `eval()` para isso é um **exagero**, Python tem funcionalidade e APIs internas que resolvem bem muitas coisas, no seu caso bastaria fazer um `for` para tratar todos dados.

Para remover os `\n` pode usar `.replace()` dentro do for mesmo e para o os `"` que precise remover somente as dos limites da string, neste caso pode usar `.strip()`, exemplo:

```
lista = ['"11/07/2019"', '"00:58:40"', '"087974440345"', '""', '"Cancelamento automático"\n', '""\n']

lista = [value.replace('\n', '').strip('"') for value in lista]

print(lista)
```

Retornando:

```
['11/07/2019', '00:58:40', '087974440345', '', 'Cancelamento automático', '']
```

Basicamente foi criado uma nova lista com os valores tratados, então dentro de `[...]` temos:

- O valor que será tratado e adicionado a nova lista `value.replace('\n', '').strip('"')`
- O que lê item por item da lista: `for value in lista`

Note também que no resultado alguns itens são strings vazias, neste caso pode usar `filter()` para remover, retornando:

```
['11/07/2019', '00:58:40', '087974440345', 'Cancelamento automático']
```

Agora se desejar filtrar os valores basta passar a condição após o `for`, supondo que queira ignorar os itens vazios, faça assim:

```
lista = ['"11/07/2019"', '"00:58:40"', '"087974440345"', '""', '"Cancelamento automático"\n', '""\n']

lista = list(filter(lambda value: value != '', [value.replace('\n', '').strip('"') for value in lista]))

print(lista)
```

Talvez não esteja muito bonito de olhar, então se preferir pode fazer assim também:

```
lista = ['"11/07/2019"', '"00:58:40"', '"087974440345"', '""', '"Cancelamento automático"\n', '""\n']

relista = []

for value in lista:
    value = value.replace('\n', '').strip('"')

    if value != '':
        relista.append(value)

print(relista)
```

Aqui neste exemplo já tratamos e checamos com o `if` se é um item vazio, se deseja remover os valores vazios, se não for o caso, ajuste para:

```
relista = []

for value in lista:
    relista.append( value.replace('\n', '').strip('"'))

print(relista)
```

Comment: Guilherme, obrigado por sua resposta completa e bem explicada. Compreendi e vou estudar cada caso.